# Get all xml files from a certain folder with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

I have following Question: I know how to load a certain XML file from a folder with AJAX. Can I load all XML files from a certain folder without naming them specifically? I tried something like but it won't work.

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "xml/*.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: xmlParser
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that the URL property of your AJAX needs to point to a particular file. As in:

```
url: "xml/myXMLFile.xml,
```

Comment: But is it possible to load multiple xml files at once without a specific filename?